# How to send state from child hook to parent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a drop down that i am attempting to get the state from and pass it to its parent container. I am having a lot of issues trying to solve this. This is my code below:

```
this.state = {
  title: null,
  postBody: null,
  giphyUrl: null,
  userIdto: null,

  displayGifPicker: false
}
```

Above is the state, I want to enter enter the value the drop down gives into UserIdto

```
    getUserTo = (selectedUser) => {
  console.log(selectedUser)
  this.setState({ userIdto : selectedUser});
}
```

The method is passed to the componenet as a prop

```
<NameDropDown onChange={this.getUserTo}/>
```

And in the parent component I have the following:

```
class PostBox extends Component {



constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      title: null,
      postBody: null,
      giphyUrl: null,
      userIdto: null,

      displayGifPicker: false
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    event.target.reset();
    const data = this.state
    //data.title if you want single item, this will help when sending req to db
    console.log("Final Output is: ", data)

    fetch('/posts/add', { 
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify ({
          title: data.title,
          postBody: data.postBody,
           giphyUrl: data.giphyUrl,
           approved: 1,
           postPicture: 'myurl.com',
              userId: 1,
              userIdto: 2
        })
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
        console.log(data.postBody)
      }).then(function(body) {
        console.log(body);
      });
  }

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.name)
    console.log(event.target.value)
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }

  displayGifPicker = () => {
    this.setState({
      displayGifPicker: !this.state.displayGifPicker
    })
}

getGifState = (selectedUrl) => {
  this.setState({ giphyUrl: selectedUrl})
}

getUserTo = (selectedUser) => {
  console.log(selectedUser)
  this.setState({ userIdto : selectedUser});
}

//  getUserTo = (name) => (event) => {
//   console.log(event.target.value)
//   this.setState({ userIdto: event.target.value });

// };

  render () {
    const {title, postBody} = this.state
    const displayGifPicker = this.state.displayGifPicker
    return (
      <Grid item xl={8}>
     {/* <Card className={classes.card} style={mt4}>  */}
     <Card style={mt4}> 
      <CardContent >
          <NameDropDown onChange={this.getUserTo}/> 
          <PostInput onChange={this.handleInputChange} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
          {displayGifPicker ? (<AddGif selectedGif = {this.getGifState} />) : (<Button size="small" onClick={this.displayGifPicker} ><button>Add Gif</button></Button>)}
        <CardActions>
        {/* <Button size="small">Submit VH5</Button> */}
        </CardActions>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  </Grid>
    )
  }
}

export default PostBox;
```

I Would like after selecting the value in the child component for it to send it to the state of the parent component in userIdTo.

This is the child function

```
    export default function NameDropDown({onChange}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    open: false,
    name: '',
  });

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setState({ ...state, open: true });
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setState({ ...state, open: false });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleClickOpen}>Select User To Send VH5</Button>
      <Dialog disableBackdropClick disableEscapeKeyDown open={state.open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle>Select a User</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <form className={classes.container}>
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">User</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={state.name}
                onChange={onChange}
                onChange={handleChange('name')}
                input={<Input id="age-simple" />}
              >
                <MenuItem value="">
                  <em>None</em>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={'Julio'}>Julio</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={'Corey'}>Corey</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={'Brenda'}>Brenda</MenuItem>
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          </form>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Ok
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: NameDropDown is your child component right ? can you show it?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: can you show the code in NameDropDown ?

Comment: sorry just uploaded it

Answer (score 0):

okay what i got from it is that first you have two onChange event listener on Select
just have one onChange that you have in your child component as

```
<Select
  value={state.name}
  onChange={handleChange('name')}
  input={<Input id="age-simple" />}
 >
```

than inside your handle change call onChange passed into props with the value as

```
const handleChange = name => event => {
 setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.value });
 onChange(event.target.value)
}
```

this way your parents state will be updated

hope it helps

Comment: Ahhh i see now, Thank you so much.

Comment: no problem glad to help, if its the right solution you can accept the answer, thanks